# Problema con barra de navegacion hamburgesa responsive que no se contrae

Tags: html, angular, typescript, scss, navbar

La barra de navegación de mi proyecto en Angular (15.2.2) es responsive y tiene un menú hamburguesa para la versión móvil, solo que no he podido lograr que se contraiga cuando se hace clic afuera de ella o en sus enlaces. La única forma es volviendo a hacer clic en el botón del menú hamburguesa, lo cual es engorroso.
Este es el código HTML, SCSS y Typescript:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav',
  templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav.component.scss']
})
export class NavComponent {

public active : boolean = false

constructor(){
  
}

setActive():void{
  this.active =!this.active
  
}

}
```

```html
<nav role="navigation" class="nav">
    <a routerLink="/">
        <img src="/assets/images/masoterapiaoli-logo.svg" class="logo" alt="logo" loading="lazy">
    </a>
    <button 
        (click)=" setActive() "
        class="button">
        <svg class="nav-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M2.5 12a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5z"/>
        </svg>
    </button>
    <ul class="nav-menu" [ngClass]="{'nav-menu-active':active}">
        <li><a routerLink="/" class="nav-link">INICIO</a></li>
        <li><a routerLink="/terapias" class="nav-link">TERAPIAS</a></li>
        <li><a routerLink="/turnos" class="nav-link">TURNOS</a></li>
        <li><a routerLink="/contacto" class="nav-link">CONTACTO</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Desde ya agradeceré cualquier ayuda porque en Typescript no he podido lograr que el menú hamburguesa se contraiga.
Saludos!

Comment: Quieres que cuando se haga click en una opción se cierre el menú?

Comment: Hola René! Exactamente. Lo que no consigo es que se cierre al hacer clic en otro lado que no sea el menú.   Dejo aquí el deploy, por si no se entiende mi problema:   https://masoterapiaoli.netlify.app/

Comment: Usando un booleano, agrega un `*ngIf` al `ul`: `<ul *ngIf="menuVisible">` y cuando se haga click en un elemento de la lista se haga `false`, `<li (click)="menuVisible = false">`

Comment: Hola de nuevo. Perdón @René, pero he logrado llevar tu consejo a medias, porque al hacer clic en los "li" el menú se contrae y desaparece pero al volver a clickear en el botón del menú hamburguesa para llamar de nuevo al menú este no vuelve a aparecer. Hice lo siguiente: `código`<ul class="nav-menu" [ngClass]="{'nav-menu-active':active}" *ngIf="menuVisible">
        <li (click)="menuVisible = false"><a routerLink="/" class="nav-link">INICIO</a></li></ul>`código` y en el TS   `código` menuVisible: boolean = true; `código`

Answer (score 2):

Lo que puedes hacer es reutilizar la función `setActive()` para cuando se haga click sobre un elemento de la lista, se oculte el menú. Al menos así lo pude hacer funcionar, agrego código:

**Componente**

```
ocultar: boolean = false;

ocultarBarra() {
  this.ocultar = !this.ocultar;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<h2 class="mt-5">Menú</h2>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="ocultarBarra()">
  Mostrar / Ocultar
</button>
<hr />
<ul class="list-group" *ngIf="!ocultar">
  <li
    *ngFor="let item of templateMenu"
    class="list-group-item"
    [routerLink]="[item.ruta]"
    routerLinkActive="active"
    (click)="ocultarBarra()"
  >
    {{ item.texto }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Resultado**

Probándolo tanto en vista de escritorio como de dispositivo móvil funciona igual, se oculta la barra al hacer click sobre cualquier elemento de la lista.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!